# How to Clear Highlighted Bookmarks?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, pdf, bookmarks

I am using a `bookmark` package, and it works fine only that I do not want the contents or citations to be highlighted within a box. Can any one tell me how to make it invisible ? 
This is the code I used:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{Contents}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{P}
Some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean the boxes around links? If so, this is not bookmark's fault! Try `\usepackage[bookmarks=true,linkbordercolor={1 1 1}]{hyperref}` and `\usepackage{tocbibind}`, this will yield `\pdfbookmark` unnecessary!

Comment: It is like there are boxes surrounding the contents, links and citations. Cant it be made invisible ? or can i change the color of the boxes ?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `linkbordercolor={1 1 1}` is *not* invisible, it's white and can be seen, if there is something non-white below. Option `hidelinks` is the better option.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: It was my first 'remembrance' only, strangely I rather remember the `...bordercolor=....` options than `hidelinks`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, for example -- the usual links are printed with blue color then (as chosen here), to make them outstanding at links, citations will still remain green, since `citecolor=green` is the default value.

Shorter, but not recommened by me: `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}` since this won't indicate links as such.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[bookmarks=true,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
%or
%\usepackage[bookmarks=true,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage
%\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{Contents}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{P}
Some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works fine for table of contents, but the citations still have a green box around it and in the bibliography, the link to the author's site contains blue box. I want to remove that also. Thank You.

Comment: @Navneeth: See the updated code please ;-)

Comment: hide links works perfectly....thanks a lot.